# ListView with fragment issue on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-listfragment

I have created a list view with a fragment, but there is some issue. Check the below image.

[image]

It happens only when the screen rotate. My code is below:

```
public class LListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    private String[] line;

    public static final String[] TITLES = { "Henry IV (1)", "Henry V",
            "Henry VIII", "Richard II", "Richard III", "Merchant of Venice",
            "Othello", "King Lear" };

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, TITLES));
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), lineDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("selected_line", "" + TITLES[position]);

        startActivity(intent);
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: now you can see image..

Comment: Have you tried a normal ListFragment, just as a test?

Comment: yes i have used both SherlockListFragment and ListFragment. but, both have same issue....

Comment: Looks like the screen isn't redrawing the layout when you rotate the screen back to portrait mode

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `ListFragment` for a similar layout and I'm not getting this problem. Try using your own `Adapter` for your list Items. Something like this

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = MyAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private List<String> _items;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(List<String> items, Context context) {
        _items = items;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return (_items != null) ? _items.size() : 0;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return (_items != null) ? _items.get(position) : null;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout, null);
        }

        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemText)).setText(_items.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


    public synchronized void refresAdapter(List<String> items) {
        _items.clear();
        _items.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**--- EDIT ---**

Here is the code for my `ListFragment`

```
public class HomeListFragment extends ListFragment implements DataListener {

    private MyAdapter _adapter;
    private Context _ctx;

    public HomeListFragment(){}

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        _ctx = getActivity();

        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        _adapter = new MyAdapter(new List<String>(), _ctx);

        setListAdapter(_adapter);

        final SomeServiceHandler s = new SomeServiceHandler(_ctx, HomeListFragment.this);
        s.request(RequestType.GETSOMEDATA, "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        //do stuff
    }

    /**
    * Listener method that is invoked by SomeServiceHandler
    */
    public void onResponseRecieved(List<String> responseList) {
        _adapter.refresAdapter(responseList);
    }
}
```

The only thing that I can see that I'm doing differently than you is that I'm refreshing my adapter after the Activity is created again by calling the `SomeServiceHandler` class and then refreshing with the response in the `onResponseRecieved` method.

Answer (score 0):

> It happens only when screen rotate.

Put this in your mainfest, as part of the activity that runs the fragment. I've used it in my apps to prevent weird things from happening when the screen rotates.

`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"`

The full Activity declaration would look something like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```